# Making calls to the shopify storefront api in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, graphql

I'm testing using the shopify storefront api, and want to access it using an ajax call. This api uses graphql, so I'm loosely following instructions for that from https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/graphql-and-jquery-kohj2aengo/

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'https://my-test-shopify-store.myshopify.com/api/graphql',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "my_storefront_access_token"},
    data: JSON.stringify({"query":"{shop{name}}"}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("successful post");
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('errors');
    }
});
```

I expect this to return a json string "My Test Shopify Store", but am getting nothing. Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data);` in your success callback instead of error callback? Check in your browser's console for any errors.

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting it in either, or both. 'errors' gets logged either way, nothing more when it is in the success function, and Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"} gets returned when I have it in the error function.

Comment: put this line in your success callback: console.log(data.data.shop.name);

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the API version in the url and `.json` at the end. Lastly you are not logging the `data` in your `success` callback. See the modified code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'https://my-test-shopify-store.myshopify.com/api/2021-01/graphql,json',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "my_storefront_access_token"},
    data: JSON.stringify({"query":"{shop{name}}"}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("successful post");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('errors');
    }
});
```